# Can I ignore build folder from master branch? - Yeoman Deployments using Git Subtree

Tags: git, deployment, version-control, yeoman

Yeoman's [deployment](http://yeoman.io/deployment.html) page, describes the process of committing the build folder (aka "dist") to the repo, then pushing that folder as a git subtree with the following command.

`git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages`

I've got that working fine, and am able to deploy only build code from dist folder from my build subtree branch (gh-pages in example above).

Can I now .gitignore this `dist` folder from master? If so, will `git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages` keep working?

If not, how might I avoid committing built source to master branch, while keeping it in a **Git Subtree** for deploying? *(Need to keep it in a branch because I use Capistrano for deployments, which, sort of, relies on deploying an entire branch to the server.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.gitignore` files do not remove existing files from the repository, and do not prevent you from committing files that are ignored. If you ignore files after they are committed, they will stay in your repository untouched, though changes to them will be ignored. If you want to commit changes to an ignored file (or a file that was committed and then ignored), you can use `git add -f` to forcibly add the ignored changes.

To answer your question more directly, I have a feeling that `git subtree` will be okay with you deleting the files after you push the subtree. Also, you should be able to run `git checkout gh-pages` to grab the `gh-pages` branch for updating your deploy.

**Alternate method:** The page you linked to has a link to a [git directory deploy script](https://github.com/X1011/git-directory-deploy) that you may find useful.

Comment: I like this answer. The alternate method link specifically states, "it does not require the generated files be committed to the source branch." This seems to be the reason this project was created.

Perhaps this makes your previous recommendations obsolete, but I still like this answer.